# Offset is not working in foursquare venue api?

Tags: foursquare

Here is my link which provides the results for foursuqare venues, but when I apply the offset from 0 to 2 and so on.., it provides me the same results in each run.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search/?client_id=02QKHPZJXGAVG3FIFSTQMBEG4VBLFARBIAZUWKKKJKQYJMN4&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20140905&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06373d81259&ll=23.039568000000003,72.56600399999999&limit=2&offset=0&radius=10000&v=20140905

Changing offset doesn't provide different results and provides the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no `offset` parameter for `venues/search` endpoint. The API is just ignoring your offset parameter. Pagination isn't possible in that endpoint. You can set limit to 50 which is max value, and change lat, lng values a bit each time to get as many venues as you can.

Answer (score 1):

offset parameter can be used along with venues/explore. It simply ignores offset parameter in venues/search. 
If offset parameter is important in your code, then you should go with venues/explore instead of search.